# How to create email verification on Firebase simple login

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

In angularfire seed project, there is an account registration process using email and password. But how can we verify that the email is not fake? I mean it is without server code, just client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can angularjs-fire seed project at this link [angularfire_seed_with_reg_confirmation](https://github.com/ciptohadi79/angularjsfire-with-reg-confirmation). Some explanation of it here [email verification using angularjs+firebase](http://www.ciptohadi.web.id/2014/05/email-verification-using-angularjs-firebase.html) Below is the quote from its readme:

> It is AngularJS seed with Firebase backend and a feature for account
>   registration confirmation via email. This feature can be used as an
>   alternative for account activation. It is a clone of AngularFire Seed
>   with additional feature above and also login feature vial social login
>   ie login with Facebook, Twitter, and Google.
>
> The account registration differs significantly from the original seed.
>   We can register for an account just by supplying an email and then
>   we'll get a confirmation email about our temporary random password.
>   The password is recommended to be changed to a memorable one and at
>   the same time it must also be strong and secure.

Comment: having checked the link, it seems work at an alternative to email verification. thanks for your answer.

Comment: you're welcome. you can fork, clone, pull req, and report issues or give suggestion to the repository. any contributions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Store a token in the database send the same token via e-mail to the client ask them to click a link in the e-mail that passes the token back to a page which marks their e-mail as verified.

Comment: hmm, so. we: 
-define user data with a property "verified" (initially set to false).
-send token to their email
-user click link+token
-compare the token, if they're same, set verified to true

-I've got it. but it will need server code to send email, whereas firebase haven't got one.
But it's brilliant idea, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a good answer, but we are angular, and we **want** to stay client-side... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS This kind of thing isn't really possible in the browser alone since the client machine and network aren't going to be configured to allow any communication from the outside, plus the things allowed by email clients is limited and varied.

Comment: Of course, just joking... :-) However, I'd consider looking for a sendmail web service (possibly free or very cheap)...

Comment: Gotcha didn't catch the sarcasm in the text but yeah using some free or cheap email solution is viable.  I personally setup postfix on my server but its a fair amount of work.  Either way though still need some persistence for the token.  Alternatively, one could use OAuth or some other third party authorization service if they don't have the time to properly secured things (I use phpass and fail2ban to help with security along with SSL)