# Security flaw with Firebase's Simple Email & Password Login?

Tags: email, authentication, firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

Firebase's Simple Login feature includes the [ability to log users in with Email & Password.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html)

This feature is very useful, and is very simple to use. However, in my attempt to implement this into a client-only web app, I seem to have identified a problem that could be addressed by Firebase easily.

However, I trust myself very little, and I always presume that I am being an idiot. So I decided to post it as a question here, instead of contacting Firebase directly, so that smart people can correct me and suggest me smart ways to deal with the seeming issue that I have come across!

*Here's my thought:*

There is a big issue that Firebases's Email simple login does not have an email confirmation feature. This means that users can create email & password accounts without actually having control of the email address.

This is a common pain point, and the most prevalent solution seems to create the user account with a random password, and immediately send them a password reset email so that they can set their own password if and only if they have control of the email.

However, since the app is client-side, even the random password assignment has to be done on client-side. Further, this does not stop someone from using the javascript command to simply creating themselves a user account with a defined. (i.e. users can still create accounts with email addresses they do not own.)

Email confirmation is crucial to building a secure client-side webapp, and I propose an easy solution:

Firebase can have an optional setting in the simple login dashboard that, when enabled, **only** allows users to be created without a working password. This way, users cannot use javascript codes to create themselves accounts with other people's email, and developers can truly make a secure client-side app by creating a user without a working password, and sending them a password-reset email, only allowing accounts with valid email addresses.

I, in my limited understanding, believe that this would be easy for Firebase to implement, yet very important for developers. However, I would not be surprised if there is already a way to limit accounts to valid email addresses, and I am just being silly.

Please enlighten me!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723195/is-there-any-way-to-do-email-confirmation-for-firebase-user-creation-and-or-pass and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946937/how-to-create-email-verification-on-firebase-simple-login. Also: http://andreasmcdermott.com/web/2014/02/05/Email-verification-with-Firebase/ and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qS9tuoBU3DY.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
yes, I have already read that thread. There are no client-side solution that really prevents users from creating spoofed accounts in the browser console!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Firebase's implementation of the simple login assumes that the entered email address simply isn't a string used to distinguish between users (i.e. it's not just a username). E.g. automatically checks for basic validity of the email address, sends password reset emails to the user email address, etc. I think it is silly to treat the email address as simply identifying string, when even the firebase's implementation assumes that the email is valid...

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
Yeah, unless email password reset could be forced, as described in the solution I proposed, or email confirmation is implemented, I don't think I would ever recommend using email&password for the auth. I'm currently resorting to use facebook auth instead for this reason...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a security risk here: Firebase just asks users to enter an email address to uniquely identify them. They could just as easily have asked for a username, but that would have lead to more user-name conflicts.

If your application wants to email the user on that address, it should verify that email address. [This blog post](http://andreasmcdermott.com/web/2014/02/05/Email-verification-with-Firebase/) describes how one person has done that.

None of my Firebase applications don't send out email, so I don't really care if the email address is valid. Just that they consistently identify the same user, which -as far as I can tell- they do.

That said: it would indeed be nice if Firebase would have the option to validate the email address as you suggest. From [this discussion on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qS9tuoBU3DY) that already seems to be on their radar. But as I said at the start: I don't think that increases security of Firebase's Simple Login.

Comment: Firebase's implementation of the simple login assumes that the entered email address simply isn't a string used to distinguish between users (i.e. it's not just a username). E.g. automatically checks for basic validity of the email address, sends password reset emails to the user email address, etc. I think it is silly to treat the email address as simply identifying string, when even the firebase's implementation assumes that the email is valid..

Comment: Yes, I have seen that blog post as well, and I have already addressed that method in my original post.

However, this method still does not stop users from creating themselves accounts with non-random passwords in the console

Comment: Hmmm... good one, I didn't think of the password resets. I must admit, I never allowed email users with Firebase, just the other (OAuth-based) ones.

Comment: Yeah, unless email password reset could be forced, as described in the solution I proposed, or email confirmation is implemented, I don't think I would ever recommend using email&password for the auth. I'm currently resorting to use facebook auth instead for this reason...

Comment: Facebook is the only OAuth one I didn't enable. :-)  From today's news Google authentication might soon be the default.